# How to strech YouTube embed video?

Tags: html, css, video, iframe, embed

I'm trying to set youtube video as bredcrumb background, I get stuck with setting video width to full screen size. As you will see the image below video is showed in the center of iframe and its not streched to full screen.

[image]

*/Black bars from left and right the video/*

**Thats my code:**

```css
#myVideo {
 position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
   width: 100vw; /*now it is 100% of viewport (window) width.*/
   display: inline-block;
  min-height: 100%;
  z-index: -99;

}
```

```html
<div id="myVideo" >
 <iframe width="100%" height="300px;" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/eLZUlh1AwrM?loop=1&autoplay=1&playlist=eLZUlh1AwrM&disablekb=1&controls=0&fs=0&modestbranding=1&mute=1&showinfo=0&enablejsapi=1&widgetid=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen ></iframe>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because YouTube maintains the proportions. If you want it to fill the width of the page, you should then increase the height too.

Comment: Alright, but I want to place it as breadcrumb background, so cant increase the height. Is it possible to crop it, or something..?

Comment: If your page hasn't scroll then you can increase the height and in the css file write ``html, body { overflow: hidden; }``

Answer (score 0):

First, wrap your div in another div element that will have fixed position.
Then, you set CSS for the `myVideo` element and `iframe` you have, using absolute position and full height/width for both.

Finally, for this to work, you need some media queries based on the aspect ratio, after and before 16/9, to position it correctly. You can test different position properties too.

```css
.video-wrapper {
  background: #000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#myVideo, .video-wrapper iframe {
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  #myVideo { height: 300%; top: -100%; }
}
@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  #myVideo { width: 300%; left: -100%; }
}
```

```html
<div class="video-wrapper">
  <div id="myVideo" >
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/eLZUlh1AwrM?loop=1&autoplay=1&playlist=eLZUlh1AwrM&disablekb=1&controls=0&fs=0&modestbranding=1&mute=1&showinfo=0&enablejsapi=1&widgetid=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen ></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```